# How do I load/mount my config .yaml file when starting Azure App Service container?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm trying to load my .yaml file as config when starting the container.

In Docker locally, I would run this:

```
docker run -dt -p 4318:4318 -v C:/Repo/MyProject/otelconfig.yaml:/etc/otelcol/config.yaml otel/opentelemetry-collector
```

How do I do this part specifically: `-v C:/Repo/MyProject/otelconfig.yaml:/etc/otelcol/config.yaml` when starting Azure App Service for container?

I have tried using Docker compose option when spawning App Service, but not sure how do I mount a single file, because in WebUI I can only mount a directory from Azure Files instead of a single file. Below is my docker-compose.yml that I used:

```
version: "1"
services:
  otel:
    image: otel/opentelemetry-collector-contrib
    init: true
    restart: always
    volumes:
      # This is the problematic part, because in web UI, I can only define 'basicdemostorage' as a directory but not a file
      - basicdemostorage:/etc/otelcol/config.yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have tried using Docker compose option when spawning App Service, but not sure how do I mount a single file,

**I have tried to repro the same scenario using the nginx docker image.**

I have followed the below steps and it is working as expected.

**Step 1:** Create azure app service (linux).

**Step 2:** Add the below app setting in configuration.

```
WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=TRUE
```

[image]

**Step 3:** Login to Kudu portal and add index.html file.
**Note: I am passing index.html file to the nginx image to easily identify the change.**

[image]

[image]

**Step 4:** Add or modify **docker-compose.yaml** file volume block in app service deployment center and click on **save**.

[image]

```
      - ${WEBAPP_STORAGE_HOME}/index.html:/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html
```

verify the webapp by accessing the URL.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I hope you got it working as this response is a little late to the party. I got the collector running in an Azure Container App by following these two blog posts.

The first is how to get it running to work with Honeycomb. I adjusted mine to work with a different APM supplier. In essence you need a Storage Account with an Azure File Share where you upload your config yaml file used when starting the collector. You create your container app with either the collector or contrib image (I used the latter) and mount the Storage Account file, so it can be read at start up.

[How to run the OTel Collector in an Azure Container App](https://www.honeycomb.io/blog/opentelemetry-collector-azure-container-apps)

This didn't quite work for me and I came to the same conclusion as you, that when running on my local machine in Docker I would send through the start up 'Command' pointing at the config file. This lead me to this blog post that added one line to the app configuration yaml file behind your container app to point at the config file and fixed the problem.

[Additional note that fixed my issue with the Honeycomb article](https://blog.depechie.com/posts/2022-10-13-opentelemetry-on-azure-container-apps/)